# Converting imported datetime from character to number without losing precision

Tags: r

I am using `read.xlsx` to loop through multiple .xlsx files which will be aggregated into a single data frame.  The issue I am running into is when the date-time field is pulled into the data frame it is being stored as a character data type with high levels of precision:

The data from the Excel file is below:

```
10/09/2015 08:15:32
10/09/2015 08:15:33
10/09/2015 08:15:34
10/09/2015 08:15:35
10/09/2015 08:15:36
10/09/2015 08:15:37
10/09/2015 08:15:38
10/09/2015 08:15:39
10/09/2015 08:15:40
10/09/2015 08:15:41
10/09/2015 08:15:42
10/09/2015 08:15:43
10/09/2015 08:15:44
10/09/2015 08:15:45
10/09/2015 08:15:46
10/09/2015 08:15:47
10/09/2015 08:15:48
10/09/2015 08:15:49    
10/09/2015 08:15:51
10/09/2015 08:15:52
```

Data after being read into dataframe:

```
class(dfCTS$DateTime)
# [1] "character"
print(dfCTS$DateTime)[1:20]
#  [1] "42286.34412037037"  "42286.344131944446" "42286.344143518516" "42286.344155092593" "42286.344166666669" "42286.344178240739" "42286.344189814816" "42286.344201388885" "42286.344212962962" "42286.344224537039"
# [11] "42286.344236111108" "42286.344247685185" "42286.344259259262" "42286.344270833331" "42286.344282407408" "42286.344293981485" "42286.344305555554" "42286.344317129631" "42286.344340277778" "42286.344351851854"
```

When I attempt to convert the character data type to numeric and back to date-time I am losing date-times and also getting duplicates which I assume is due to a losing precision or having too much precision.

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(dfCTS$DateTime) * (60*60*24), origin = "1899-12-30", tz = "GMT")[1:20]
#  [1] "2015-10-09 08:15:32 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:33 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:34 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:35 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:36 GMT""2015-10-09 08:15:37 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:38 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:38 GMT"
#  [9] "2015-10-09 08:15:40 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:41 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:41 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:43 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:44 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:45 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:46 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:47 GMT"
# [17] "2015-10-09 08:15:48 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:49 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:51 GMT" "2015-10-09 08:15:52 GMT"
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do.  Do you want to read the file directly into R as POSIXct?

Comment: It's not clear that you're losing precision.  You start with seconds and end up with the same as far as I can tell i.e. your excel data matches the POSIXct shown.  And as @Richard Scriven asks, why convert at all and what is the goal?

Comment: What's printed on the console in R is not necessarily what is stored. Precision to a second level will be all that is printed even if there is sub-second precision data available.

Comment: Please check my answer. I had posted it yesterday but was unsure if it was what you wanted so I deleted it.  Undeleted now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a reason you are doing all those intermediate conversions, but if you want to read the data directly from the file into a POSIXct column, here are two options.

**Option 1:** Set a custom class using `as.POSIXct()`.  Just replace `text = txt` with your file name in `read.table()` below.

```
setClass("myPOSIX")
setAs(
    "character", 
    "myPOSIX", 
    function(from) as.POSIXct(from, format = "%m/%d/%Y %T", tz = "GMT")
)    
df <- read.table(text = txt, sep = "\n", colClasses = "myPOSIX")
class(df[[1]])
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

**Option 2:** Use the `readr` package.  This is the first time I've used this package so hopefully I've done it the right way.

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv(
    txt, 
    col_names = "date", 
    col_types = cols(date = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %T"))
)
class(df$date)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

**Data:**

```
txt <- "10/09/2015 08:15:32
10/09/2015 08:15:33
10/09/2015 08:15:34
10/09/2015 08:15:35
10/09/2015 08:15:36
10/09/2015 08:15:37
10/09/2015 08:15:38
10/09/2015 08:15:39
10/09/2015 08:15:40
10/09/2015 08:15:41
10/09/2015 08:15:42
10/09/2015 08:15:43
10/09/2015 08:15:44
10/09/2015 08:15:45
10/09/2015 08:15:46
10/09/2015 08:15:47
10/09/2015 08:15:48
10/09/2015 08:15:49
10/09/2015 08:15:51
10/09/2015 08:15:52"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much.  I am still unsure why the intermediate conversions after loading the data resulted in a different output though.  Thanks again